# Accessing CryptGenRandom from PHP

Tags: php, windows, security, random

I'm having trouble finding a way to access secure random numbers on Windows from PHP in a way that will stand a good chance of working on any given installation.

- A lot of windows installs come without openssl or with it disabled, so `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` often doesn't work.
- Same kind of problem with `mcrypt_create_iv()` when mycrypt extension isn't available.
- `session_id()` (with session.entropy_length set to a resonable number) is another route but safe mode sometimes disables the functions needed to regenerate and get the session ID.
- `new COM('CAPICOM.Utilities.1')->GetRandom()` is kinda obsolete (Win32 only) and the dll isn't reliably available.
- `new DOTNET('mscorlib', 'System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider')` with `GetBytes()` only works if .NET is installed and is working compatibly with PHP.

What's a better solution?

Comment: The best solution is to use linux and `/dev/random` :) CryptGenRandom isn't very good anyway,  if you are serious you should be using an entropy pool like /dev/random.

Comment: @Rook: The requirement is that the code run on Windows. And CryptGenRandom was poor in the old days but is as good as most others now.

Comment: if its not an entropy pool or a hardware-RNG,  then its garbage and should not be used.

Comment: @Rook: CryptGenRandom's entropy pool is fed with many sources of entropy from the OS. It is of sufficient quality for commercial crypto applications and it is FIPS verified.

Comment: Do you need to specifically call [`CryptGenRandom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Is it not possible to create a helper application that uses CryptGenRandom and is launched via PHP? IPC on Windows is slower than on Unix/Linux (anecdotal) but you haven't mentioned how often you'll need random numbers.

Answer (score 4):

I have actually implemented an [RFC4086](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4086#section-5.2) compliant Random Number Generator in PHP.  You can see the work at [the GitHub Project for PHP-CryptLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-CryptLib).

Basically, you specify the "strength" of random number/string that you require.  If you need cryptographically secure numbers, select High (but note, this can be a blocking operation.  If you just need good strength numbers/strings, I'd suggest the Medium setting.  If you're just implementing a game with no security implications, choose Low.

So here's how to use it:

```
require_once dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/lib/CryptLib/bootstrap.php';
$factory = new \CryptLib\Random\Factory;
$generator = $factory->getLowStrengthGenerator();
$number = $generator->generate(8);
```

That will generate an 8 byte string (chr 0-255) at low strength (you could do ->getHighStrengthGenerator for a high one).  The difference is how it sets up the generator (which mixer it uses, and which sources it uses).

To generate an integer between 1 and 10 (inclusive):

```
$int = $generator->generateInt(1, 10);
```

Note that RFC4086 specifies a way to generate randomness from multiple sources (so that if any one source is compromised, the final result will not be significantly weakened).  So when you select the High strength source, it uses the same sources as the Medium one, but with one or more added from the high strength category.

Note that according to the RFC, the strength of the output is **at least** as good as the strongest non-compromised source being used.  So this really will be the best quality RNG for an application that you can get (the design)...  If you wanted to add a hardware TRNG, you could and still use the mechanism (the sources are plugable, so it should be able to add anything without harming the output)...

Comment: What has that answer to do with Accessing CryptGenRandom from PHP?

Comment: @hakre: Actually, the question was about generating cryptographically secure random numbers in PHP on Windows.  I showed a method of doing that (which can use multiple sources to generate it)...

Comment: This generator is not "RFC4086 compliant" except that is uses a good bit mixer. But mixing bits doesn't make a generator CS unless the bits being mixed are CS random. In the case that we have Windows and safe_mode and we do not have mcrypt or openssl, ircmaxwell's generator just mixes mt_rand, rand and microtime. So it's not CS in these situations and fails in exactly the same way that I described in the OP.

Comment: @fsb: to be pedantic, in those situations, it is **impossible** to get CS random numbers in PHP.  To try is futile.  At least this code will always generate the strongest possible random number for the particular implementation of PHP.  That was the point I was making.